# Use properties in RequestMapping value

Tags: spring, properties, controller

I want to define RequestMapping using the value inside a properties file (file inside resource folder).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "X", produces = "application/json")
public String hello() {

}
```

How can I read "X" from a properties file?

EDIT: I try with @PropertySource annotation, but it doesn't work in "X"

EDIT 2: I also try this, and it works but not in @RequestMapping(value = "X")

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    propertyConfigurer.setLocations(new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver().getResources("classpath:/**/abc.properties"));
    return propertyConfigurer;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I asked nearly the same. My problem is solved, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41767789/1988304)

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to use placeholders in @RequestMapping. Read the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-placeholders) for more details

```
@RequestMapping("${foo.bar}", produces = "application/json")
public String hello() {
    ....
}
```