# Spring controller: How to use property ${..} in @RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I already found questions with answers but they don't help me.

I have a web servlet project where I use a Spring Controller (4.2.5) and Spring Security (4.0.2). I don't use Spring Boot.

My project works fine.

But now my task is this:
**Make `@RequestMapping(value={"auth/**"}` configurable** (replace `"auth/**"` with `${dm.filterPattern}`)

**Problem: in `@RequestMapping` `${dm.filterPattern}` isn't resolved, although @PropertySource is processed.**

This is the entry `dm.filterPattern` in dmConfig.properties:

```
dm.filterPattern=/auth/*
```

Here is some essential code, with all Spring annotations.

#### Controller:

The output of the method `init()` shows me that `@PropertySource` is processed correctly. `env.getProperty("...")` returns correct values.

```java
@Controller
@PropertySource("classpath:/dmConfig.properties")
@RequestMapping(value ={ "${dm.filterPattern}"})
public class DmProxyController implements ApplicationContextAware
{
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    public DmProxyController(Environment env)
    {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @RequestMapping(path={"${dm.filterPattern}"} ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest customerRequest, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, DmException
    {
           // code for POST request
    }

    @RequestMapping(path={"${dm.filterPattern}"} ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest customerRequest, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, DmException
    {
           // code for GET request
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws ServletException
    {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMapping=
                (RequestMappingHandlerMapping) appContext.getBean("requestMappingHandlerMapping");

        Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> handlerMethods = requestMapping.getHandlerMethods();
        logger.debug("RequestMapping via dm.filterPattern: {}",
                env.getProperty("dm.filterPattern"));
                logger.debug("Handler Methods: {}", handlerMethods.size());

        for (RequestMappingInfo mapInfo : handlerMethods.keySet())
        {
            logger.debug(" Mappinginfo: {} --> {}", mapInfo, handlerMethods.get(mapInfo));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Class with bean definitions

```java
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/dmConfig.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.dm.filter, com.dm.controller")
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY, proxyTargetClass = false)
@Import({DmSecurityConfigurer.class, DmWebConfigurer.class})
public class DmRoot
{

}
```

#### DispatcherServletInitializer

```java
public class DmDispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    { return new Class[]{DmRoot.class};  }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    { return null; }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    { return new String[]{"/"}; }

    @Override
    protected String getServletName()
    {  return "dmDispatcherServlet";  }

    @Override
    protected void customizeRegistration(ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration)
    {
        super.customizeRegistration(registration);
        registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

#### WebConfigurer

```java
public class DmWebConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/index.html").addResourceLocations("/");
        registry.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE-5);
    }
}
```

#### SecurityWebApplicationInitializer

```java
public class DmSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer
{
    public DmSecurityWebApplicationInitializer()
    {
        // some logging
    }

    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext)
    {     // adding own filters   }

    @Override
    protected void afterSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext)
    {     // adding own filters   }
}
```

#### SecurityConfigurer

```java
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableWebSecurity
@PropertySource("classpath:dmConfig.properties")
public class DmSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DmSecurityConfigurer.class.getName());

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService dmUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception
    {
        String urlPattern = env.getProperty("dm.springSecurityPattern");
        String realmName = env.getProperty("dm.springSecurityRealm");

        httpSecurity.httpBasic().realmName(realmName)
                .and().userDetailsService(dmUserDetailsService)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(urlPattern).authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility that `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is being initialised later in the spring context than your controller and hence the values are not resolved. try adding explicit bean definition for `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` in one of the root configuration file as below;

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/dmConfig.properties")
public class DmWebConfigurer extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
    {
        super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/index.html").addResourceLocations("/");
        registry.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE-5);
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

The reason you can see the values properly in your `init()` method is because it is called after all the beans are initialised including `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: yes, it works as you described. I've put both the bean and the annotation to the class (DmRoot in my question) where I define other beans.